# Setting Width of UIView Object in TableView Cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, constraints

I thought this would be a little easier but I believe I'm stumped. Have a simple tableView with a cell. In the cell is a UIView (along with a few other UILabels) that I want to vary the width of based on values in that same cell (indexPath.row) - a simple bar graph effect for lack of a better description.

Have tried various iterations of using cell.view.frame... to access those attributes. I realize the .width property is get-only. Have also tried many variations of .constraints attributes and can't get the simple effect I am looking for.

The code is very simple tableView template code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MoreTidesCell", for: indexPath) as? MoreTidesCell {
       let formatter = DateFormatter()
       formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd"
       let prediction = predictionsHighLow[indexPath.row]
       cell.tideDateLabel.text = formatter.string(from: prediction.date)
       cell.lowestTideLabel.text = String(prediction.lowestLow.rounder(toPlaces: 1))
       cell.highestTideLabel.text = String(prediction.highestHigh.rounder(toPlaces: 1))

    // here would like to have something like...
    // cell.tideSpanBar.frame = CGRect(x: myX, y: myY, width: myWidth, height: myHeight)
    // based on the values of lowest tide and highest tide.

       return cell
   } else {
       return MoreTidesCell()
   }
}
```

Here's a simple mock of the way it would look (of course, with the blue bar varying in width).

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cti2pjpz944q8to/IMG_1840.jpeg

I realize there are constraints at play, so my guess is that the solution with be more constraint-related than .width related. Just looking for a solid reference point to start building this out. One of the only problems in my short Swift learning curve that has completely shut me down. Appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: FYI - the logic for setting the view's frame belong in the cell class, not in `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: Also, get rid of the `if let` and the `else`. Just force-cast the dequeued cell. You want it to crash if the cast fails so you can fix the issue early in development.

Comment: Not sure I understand the first part of your answer (my ignorance). I thought if I wanted to vary the frame with in each cell, it would have to be done at cellForRowAt.

Comment: The cell class should be responsible for its own views. The only thing you should do in `cellForRowAt` is to give the cell the data it needs.

Comment: You can override `layoutSubviews` inside of `MoreTidesCell`. After calling `super.layoutSubviews()`, you can redefine the frame for `tideSpanBar` since that's when you'll know dimensions of every view.

Comment: One of those brain-fart moments. Outlet to width constraint in custom class worked perfectly.